# Syndaemon not working any more in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I wanted to disable touchpad while typing in Ubuntu 14.04. When i tried syndaemon -i 1 -K -d, it worked at the first time, but then after logging again, the same was not working. I killed the syndaemon process and tried to rerun again, still it is not working. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the same option in System Settings -> Mouse.

It starts syndaemon with other options and they conflict.